# Mathematical symbol not displaying within spoiler on mobile site

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web

I am on Chrome for Android, and when I open the second spoiler in [this answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/102372/9802), the symbol does not display - I see the literal text `$\checkmark$` instead.

If I leave the spoiler open and add a comment, the text changes to the expected symbol.

Comment: *If I leave the spoiler open and add a comment, the text changes to the expected symbol.* Is it getting displayed now?

Comment: Maybe after you have added a comment, the page got reloaded. If you have enabled **Lite** mode, the page you already visited doesn't reload unless you reload it or perform certain actions. This may have caused it to appear so.

Comment: Hello there :-P

Comment: Is this really a duplicate? I'm referring to the mobile site, not the app.

Comment: @Ak19 I assume when you load the page or add a comment, it parses all visible content on the page. So, because the content of the spoiler isn't visible on load, it is ignored.